# Is there a simple way to output the number of rows, including missing values for each group, without aggregating them?

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to know the number of rows, whenever I want, with whatever variables and groups I want. What I want to do is to write the following 'n_groupuby' column in as short and simple code as possible. Of course, it is the number of rows, so it counts even if there are missing values. Counting without missing values is really easy with 'count'.

```
      sl   sw   pl   pw    species  n_groupby
0    5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2     setosa         50
1    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     setosa         50
..   ...  ...  ...  ...        ...        ...
149  5.9  3.0  5.1  1.8  virginica         50


from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=['sl','sw','pl','pw']).assign(species=iris.target_names[iris.target])
df.iloc[1,0:4] = None
      sl   sw   pl   pw    species
0    5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2     setosa
1    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     setosa
..   ...  ...  ...  ...        ...
149  5.9  3.0  5.1  1.8  virginica


#This does not work.
df.assign(
    n_groupby  = df.groupby('species').transform('size')
)

#This is too long.
df.merge(df.groupby('species',as_index=False).size(), how='left').rename(columns={'size':'n_groupby'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want to get a "cleaner" version of what your already doing up there, df.isna().sum() basically lists all the nan values in a Series format that's feasible to read.

`df.isna().sum()`

Thanks :)